# Endless loop when using unsigned int

Tags: c++

I have written a function that has to return n of bit "1" in binary representation. I have observed unexpected (for me) behavior.

When I'm using `unsigned int` type in a `for` loop, the function gets stuck in an endless loop, I have no idea why.

```
unsigned int countBits(unsigned long long n)
{
  //your code here
  int   nofbits=  log2(n)+1,
        nofone=0;
  for(int i=nofbits;i>=0;--i)
  {
      if(n-pow(2,i)>=0)
      {
          nofone++;
          n=n-pow(2,i);
      }
  }
    return nofone;
}
```

vs with endless loop

```
unsigned int countBits(unsigned long long n)
{
  //your code here
  int   nofbits=  log2(n)+1,
        nofone=0;
  for(unsigned i=nofbits;i>=0;--i)
  {
      if(n-pow(2,i)>=0)
      {
          nofone++;
          n=n-pow(2,i);
      }
  }
    return nofone;
}
```

Comment: Are those `log2` and `pow` actually `std::log2` and `std::pow`?

Comment: Unrelated: integer 2 to the power of an integer is better handled with left shifts. It can be much, much faster and is immune to errors introduced by flipping back and forth between integer and floating point representation.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(unsigned i=nofbits;i>=0;--i)
```

it will always be greater than 0 because it is unsigned. An unsigned number can only be >= 0.

From the comments, Remy Lebeau commented that when you subtract 1 from an unsigned 0, it will wrap around you end up with a very large number: 4294967295

Answer (score 2):

As the name of the type indicates, an `unsigned int` can never become negative. Decrementing an unsigned int value `0` results in the maximum value an unsigned int can take on. Hence, a comparison like `i >= 0` with `i` being of type `unsigned int` will always be `true`.